# make a loading bar in python for receiving a file using socket library and tcp protocol

Tags: python, tcp, python-sockets

I'm making a program in Python using the socket library with tcp protocol.
I'm trying to create a loading bar to let me know how far along I am in downloading a file from the server.
Having entered the entire size of the file to download into the recv function as a buffer, is there a way to know where I am at? Thank you

```
HEADER = "64"
FORMAT = "utf-8"

#function that receives the file from the server
def recv_msg(s):
    msg_len = s.recv(HEADER).decode(FORMAT)
    if msg_len:
        msg_len = int(msg_len)
        msg = s.recv(msg_len).decode(FORMAT)
        return msg




#function that sends the file to the client
def send_msg(conn, data):
    msg = data.encode(FORMAT)
    msg_len = len(msg)

    send_len = str(msg_len).encode(FORMAT)
    send_len += b' ' * (HEADER - len(send_len))
    conn.sendall(send_len)    
    conn.sendall(msg)
```

Comment: There is no guarantee in TCP that `recv` will return the amount requested. Check the return value and loop until you have what you want. Use that amount to calculate your progress bar as well.